# How is data actually hidden in a class?

Tags: c++, oop

```
 class student
 { 
  private :
     int rollno;
     char name[20];
  public:
     void change_stud()
     { cout<<"enter new roll no:";
       cin>>rollno;
       cout<<" new name ";
       cin.getline(name,20);
     }
    void show_student()
      { cout<<rollno<<"  "<<name;}
 }
```

Now, please explain how is `roolno` and `name` hidden members of class when we can see or change them from any outside function example `main()`

```
int main()
{
  student s1;
  s1.change_stud();
  s1.show_student();
}
```

What is the fundamental meaning of data hiding and abstraction in class ? Even when we can actually access the private members of class.

Comment: If you follow the mechanism like make your variables private and access them through some public methods(let say their Getters and setters) then you can make them hidden.Please study the mechanism of [abstraction of data](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_abstraction.htm)

Comment: You're not changing them from `main`.  That would be something like `int main() { student s1; s1.rollno = 5; }`.  Instead, you're just calling a member function.

Comment: The main function should return `int` in C++. I corrected that detail of your example.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't think main() must be int , I usually go with using void.

Comment: In standard C++, `main` must return `int`. Anything else is non-standard.

Comment: Any information about my desk is hidden to you (I hope). If you asked me which book is on my desk right now and I told you, would you really say that *you* had acccessed my desk? I would say that *I* did, and provided some bit of information about it to you; my desk isn't hidden *to me*.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this - http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/encap-is-for-code-not-people.html

I think you are misunderstanding what's meant by hiding or encapsulation.
It's mean to protect against accidentally modifying a private member - you can only do it by using public functions. It doesn't the member is totally not accessible. Nor is it a way to protect secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Data encapsulation or data hiding is achieved by specifying an `interface` on an object where the object controls how its data is manipulated.
You `call a method` on an object to pass a value to it. If the value is , i.e. out of range for the object to handle, the object can decline to accept the value and throw an exception.

What you are doing is calling the method on your objects, you are **NOT** changing the 
`private members` directly, the compiler would prohibit this.

See the [`C++-FAQ`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/classes-and-objects.html) on this particular topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call change_student() to change the value from the outside. But the outside function still does not have direct access to the variable, right? Your class Student still manages the variables. If an outside class calls the functions with illegal parameters, the Student class can still intercept those function calls, and make sure its state is kept logical.

Data hiding also means that you do not need to know of the exact name of the variable or any extra steps that need to be taken while changing it. For example suppose you have another variable that depends on how many times the student changes.

```
void change_student()
     { cout<<"enter new roll no:";
       cin>>rollno;
       cout<<" new name ";
       cin.getline(name,20);
        numberOfTimesChanged++;
     }
```

encapsulation and data hiding makes sure that the outside classes do not have to deal with the inner workings of your class. Such things will be handled by your class itself.